# Error Code: 2068 while loading csv file into MySql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am using Amazon RDS MySql for data storage. I am able to load data by specifying the column values, however, when I try to load the data from my local machine to MySql, it fails with
Error: 2068.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/priya/Documents/Atlas/data/The_Atlas_0820.csv' INTO TABLE schedule 
 FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
 ENCLOSED by '"'
 LINES TERMINATED by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (Carrier1, FlightNo1, DupCar1,DupCar2, DupCar3, 
DupCar4,DupCar5, DupCar6,DupCar7, DupCar8,DepAirport, ArrAirport);
```

**Error Code:** 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

I also checked `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';` and it is set to **"ON"**.

If i use Terminal to open a connection with MySql and execute the command there, it works ok.

```
$ ./mysql -h <hostname> -P 3306 --local_infile=1 -u <username> -p
```

**But how to make it work in MySql Workbench.**

Comment: if you have access to your file, Remove `LOCAL` may help you.

Comment: @majidhajibaba I tried removing LOCAL, It still doesn't work.
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug in MySQL Workbench for LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, check if the workaround in this link works for you:

[MySQL Workbench 8.0 restricts usage of LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91872)

or there is another solution that seems to work here:

[Workbench 8.0.12 no longer allows LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91891)

Comment: Thanks. One of the solutions worked for me. Let me share it here so that others can also benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding what worked for me here, I was able to find a working solution through the links @Zacca provided, but I had to dig through solutions that didn't work, and I thought I'd repost here in case those links die at some point.

First, if I ran `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';` I can see that `INFILE` is enabled. However, I was still getting "ERROR CODE 2068"

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
```

I was able to resolve this by editing the connection string in MySQL workbench by navigating to Home, then:

> Edit Connection > Advanced > Copy `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1` into Others box on a new line

Then restart the connection. After that, `LOAD LOCAL INFILE` runs without error.

Also, as a side note, before I found this solution, I found I could run the `LOAD LOCAL INFILE` command from R without issue, which helped me isolate the client as the issue, as opposed to a security/permissions related problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is from the workarounds shared in the link:
[Workbench 8.0.12 no longer allows LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91891) as shared by @Zacca.

Steps for Mac:

1. Create a **my.cnf** file with the following statements at the path: **/etc**.
   I created **my.cnf** file using root user.

```
[client]
port        = 3306
[mysqld]
port        = 3306
secure_file_priv=''
local-infile = 1
```

2. Set the my.cnf file as the default configuration file in MySql Workbench.
   Click the **Wrench icon** next to **Instance**.
   Under configuration file, enter the path to **my.cnf** file: **/etc/my.cnf**.
3. Restart the MySQL server workbench.
4. Try the following statements in MySQL Workbench:
   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "local_infile";  //Should be ON
   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";  //Should have no values (not NULL but blank)
5. Load the data.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '<path>/file.csv' INTO TABLE <tablename> 
 FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
 ENCLOSED by '"'
 LINES TERMINATED by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Using **LOCAL** keyword, loading is successful.
However, without **LOCAL** keyword, I get access error.

**Error Code: 1045**. Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 0):

After beating my head around this for an hour, I switched back to MySQL Workbench 6.3.
Bliss.