# How to solve MySQL Workbench ERROR 1290 on Mac?

Tags: mysql, workbench

I am trying to import a large .csv file so I cannot use the import wizard option since this file has over a million rows.

I've tried

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile= 1;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "local_infile";
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/username/Desktop/folder/data.csv' 
INTO TABLE citibike_data
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

and I get ERROR 1290. My local_infile says it is ON, but my secure_file_priv is still set to NULL. I've looked at other posts and many solutions are for Windows and I haven't found any .cnf or .ini file on my computer. I've also tried adding `OPT_LOCAL_INFILE=1;` to my connection settings, but it still isn't working.

Any suggestions are helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The `local_infile` option is not relevant, because you're using `LOAD DATA INFILE`. You probably meant to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` if you are trying to make the client read a local file and send it to a remote MySQL instance.

If you use `LOAD DATA INFILE` (without the `LOCAL` keyword), then it tries to load the file *on the MySQL server* from the path you name. This must be in a location corresponding to the `secure_file_priv` variable, which is a server option you need to enable in the server config (and it requires a restart to take effect). You also need to upload your file to that directory on the MySQL server, which is not possible if you don't have access to the server host.

Comment: I see that I forgot the LOCAL keyword and now I have ERROR 2068 and I've made sure to change the folder and file permission to make sure everyone can access the file, but I still get the same error.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in MySQL Workbench. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63788865/error-code-2068-while-loading-csv-file-into-mysql

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't use MySQL Workbench. I just use command-line tools that come with MySQL, like mysqlimport. I've found too many bugs in MySQL Workbench, it's practically useless and it hinders me more than it helps.

Comment: @BillKarwin what kind of bugs are existed on MySQL workbench? How seriously do they effect performance ? In fact, It seems to be quite good GUI to me.

Comment: @OzanSen Here is the most recent Workbench bug I commented on: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94294 It does not affect performance, but it blocks certain usage, or makes usage more confusing. Some other bugs in the past have resulted in crashes of the Workbench client, but not the MySQL Server.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you for the answer. Nice to know it. Stay safe!