# How many possible names for a MySQL config file? (my.cnf; .config, my.ini...)

Tags: mysql, windows, load-data-infile

I'm running MySQL 8.0 on just my little Windows machine (Windows 11 Pro) and I want to use LOAD LOCAL INFILE, which of course requires that I set some parameters in a file that might be called 'my.ini', or 'mysql.conf' or...  I guess there are other possibilities?

I've searched the \bin, \lib, and \etc directories in the MySQL Server directory as well as the Router and Shell directories, and I've used File Search to try and find the ones I specifically named above, but have had no luck.

I understand that I need to set the local_infile variable to ON on the server side.  I seem to have done that, using the SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON' command, and after I did the error when I tried the LOAD LOCAL INFILE command changed from

ERROR 3948 (42000): Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

to

ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.

Assuming first that I've gotten the server-side problem taken care of, what even counts as the "client" when it's running on the same machine?

Comment: there is only one, you can find it using the duplicae link and replace the version number with 8.0

Comment: Are you trying to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in MySQL Workbench? If so, read the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63788865/error-code-2068-while-loading-csv-file-into-mysql